# convert batch file to python script using sys and subprocess

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, subprocess, sys

first i use python api from some program,and to can i do that i create .bat file with the  paths and calls.

but i want to convert this .bat file(with paths and calls) to python script using `sys.paths` and `subprocess`.

---

mybatch.bat

```
set ROOT=C:\path\path 
call “%ROOT%“\path1\path1.bat 
call “%ROOT%“\path2\path2\path2\path2\path2.bat 
set GDPATH=%ROOT%\path3\path3 
path %PATH%;”%ROOT%\path4\path4\path4\” 
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%ROOT%\path4\path4\path4; 
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%ROOT%\path5\path5\path5\path5 
set SPATH=%ROOT%\path6 
start “name ide” /B “path from idle.exe”
```

the PYTHONPATH is the program python path to use api not the path from python

i want to create a script where to run or call batch file with the `subprocess`  and run on background(activate). 
and i need define path with the `sys,sys.path.extend,sys.path.append` i am not sure who is right.

any idea how can i do this convert ?i try to use call from `subprocess` and `sys.path.append` from `sys` without success.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good candidate for converting to Python, because you are changing your MS Prompt environment. Changing sys.path will change your Python path within your script, but not the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: the PYTHONPATH is the program python path to use api not the path from python